# There is no implicit reference conversion from 'type1' to 'type2'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I try to do a web project, but face an issue.

Code:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
    services.AddScoped<ILibraryAssetService, LibraryAssetService>();  
    services.AddDbContext<LibraryContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LibraryConnection")));
}
```

But I get an error :

> Error  CS0311  The type 'Library.LibraryAssetService' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddScoped(IServiceCollection)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Library.LibraryAssetService' to 'LibraryData.ILibraryAssetService'.  Library C:\Users\Austina\source\repos\Library\Library\Startup.cs    29  Active

I googled it everywhere, but nothing helped. Maybe I am missing something obvious?

Also code with class:

```
public class LibraryAssetService : ILibraryAssetService
{
    private LibraryContext _context;
    private int videoId;

    public LibraryAssetService(LibraryContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public LibraryAssetService()
    {
    }

    public void Add(LibraryAsset newAsset)
    {
        _context.Add(newAsset);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public LibraryAsset Get(int id)
    {
        return _context.LibraryAssets
            .Include(a => a.Status)
            .Include(a => a.Location)
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<LibraryAsset> All => _context.LibraryAssets
            .Include(a => a.Status)
            .Include(a => a.Location);

    public int Id => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string ImageUrl => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string Title => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string GetAuthorOrDirector(int id)
    {
        var isBook = _context.LibraryAssets
            .OfType<Book>().Any(a => a.Id == id);

        var isVideo = _context.LibraryAssets
            .OfType<Video>().Any(video => videoId == id);

        return isBook
            ? GetAuthor(id)
            : GetDirector(id);
    }

    public LibraryAsset GetById(int id)
    {
        return _context.LibraryAssets
            .Include(asset => asset.Status)
            .Include(asset => asset.Location)
            .FirstOrDefault(asset => asset.Id == id);
    }

    public LibraryBranch GetCurrentLocation(int id)
    {
        return _context.LibraryAssets.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id).Location;
    }

    public string GetDeweyIndex(int id)
    {
        if (_context.Books.Any(book => book.Id == id))
        {
            return _context.Books.FirstOrDefault(book => book.Id == id).DeweyIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public string GetIsbn(int id)
    {
        if (_context.Books.Any(a => a.Id == id))
             {
            return _context.Books
                .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id).ISBN;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
    public LibraryCard GetLibraryCardByAssetId(int id)
    {
        return _context.LibraryCards
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Checkouts
                .Select(a => a.LibraryAsset)
                .Select(v => v.Id).Contains(id));
    }

    public string GetTitle(int id)
    {
        return _context.LibraryAssets.First(a => a.Id == id).Title;
    }

    public string GetType(int id)
    {
        var book = _context.LibraryAssets.OfType<Book>()
             .Where(b => b.Id == id);
        return book.Any() ? "Book" : "Video";
    }
    private string GetAuthor(int id)
    {
        var book = (Book)Get(id);
        return book.Author;
    }
    private string GetDirector(int id)
    {
        var video = (Video)Get(id);
        return video.Director;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ILibraryAssetService> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    internal class LibraryContext_context
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another `LibraryAssetService` in another project class library?

Answer (score 4):

This should be caused by namespace conflicts, you have two classes or interfaces with the same name that live in separate namespaces.

Try to use [fully qualified namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces) like

```
services.AddScoped<LibraryData.ILibraryAssetService, Library.LibraryAssetService>();
```

you need to correct the above fully qualified namespaces since `Library.LibraryAssetService` does not implement `LibraryData.ILibraryAssetService`, as the compile error suggests.

Comment: Still the same error message? What types are you using now? `services.AddScoped<?, ?>`

Comment: Still the same,services.AddScoped<LibraryData.ILibraryAsset, LibraryData.LibraryAssetService>();

Comment: Does `LibraryData.LibraryAssetService` implements *LibraryData.ILibraryAsset*?

Comment: When I try your suggestion, the same error occurs, but VS offers to simplify names and in finish line it still gets services.AddScoped<ILibraryAsset, LibraryAssetService>(); , I tried several combinations for this, but I think I do not fully understand this part...

Answer (score 3):

You are not implementing the interface. Implement the interface by the class like this:

```
public class LibraryAssetService: ILibraryAssetService
{
///....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Answer , You have two classes or two interfaces the same name.

```
services.AddTransient<IDepartMentService,DepartMentService>();
```

**Here!!!**

- I have two the same name interface *IDepartMentService*
- I have two the same name class *DepartMentService*

Correct :Using namespace for interface and class.

```
   services.AddTransient< ClinicSystem.BOL.IServices.IDepartMentService,ClinicSystem.BLL.Services.DepartMentService>();
```

Good Luck with my Answer If You fixed your error give my vote .